# how to display selected radio button from multiple pages to last page which named is result

Tags: android, eclipse, radio-button

I am developing quiz application on mobile app. Each page contain 1 questions. it has 10 pages contains 10 questions.
I had succeed to bring selected radio button which is an answer from user from page 1 to page 10. My problem right now is I cannot display the total result at result page. How I am going to solve it

```
       import android.app.Activity;
       import android.content.Intent;
       import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.view.View;

       import android.widget.RadioButton;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        public class result extends Activity {
        public RadioButton              

        r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10,r11,r12,r13,r14,r15,r16,r17,r18,
        r19,r20,r21,r22, r23,r24,r25,r26,r27;
        TextView txt_result,outputresult;

        int result,resultAll;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.result);

    outputresult =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    r1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb1);
    r2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb2);
    r3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb3);
    r4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb4);
    r5 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb5);
    r6 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb6);
    r7 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb7);
    r8 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb8);
    r9 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb9);
    r10 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb10);
    r11 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb11); 
    r12 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb12);
    r13 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb13);
    r14 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb14);
    r15 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb15);
    r16 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb16);
    r17 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb17);
    r18 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb18);
    r19 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb19);
    r20 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb20);
    r21 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb21);
    r22 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb22);
    r23 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb23);
    r24 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb24);
    r25 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb25);
    r26 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb26);
    r27 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb27); 


    //Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),result.class);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,result.class);

     intent.putExtra("r26", getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r26"));
     intent.putExtra("r27", getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r27"));

     r1.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r1"));
     r2.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r2"));
     r3.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r3"));
     r4.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r4"));
     r5.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r5"));
     r6.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r6"));
     r7.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r7"));
     r8.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r8"));
     r9.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r9"));
     r10.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r10"));
     r11.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r11"));
     r12.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r12"));
     r13.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r13"));
     r14.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r14"));
     r15.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r15"));
     r16.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r16"));
     r17.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r17"));
     r18.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r18"));
     r19.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r19"));
     r20.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r20"));
     r21.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r21"));
     r22.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r22"));
     r23.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r23"));
     r24.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r24"));
     r25.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r25"));
     r26.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r26"));
     r27.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r27"));




    if (r1.isChecked())
    {


        result= 0;

    }

    else if (r2.isChecked())
    {
        result= 1;

    }
    else if(r3.isChecked())
    {
        result= 0;
    }

        result+=1;


     if(r4.isChecked())
     {
         result=0;
     }

     else if (r5.isChecked())
      {
        result= 1;
      }

     result+=1;


     if (r6.isChecked())
     {
     result= 0;

     }


  else if (r7.isChecked())
      {
        result= 0;
      }


  else if (r8.isChecked())
      {
        result= 1;
      }


     result+=1;


     if (r9.isChecked())
       {
        result= 0;
       }


     else if (r10.isChecked())
       {
        result= 0;
       }

     else if (r11.isChecked())
       {
        result= 1;
       }

     result+=1;


     if (r12.isChecked())
     {
     result= 0;
     }


     else if (r13.isChecked())
      {
        result= 0;
      }

     else if (r14.isChecked())
      {
        result= 1;
      }

     result+=1;


      if (r15.isChecked())
       {
        result= 1;
       }


       else if (r16.isChecked())
        {
        result= 0;
        }

      else if (r17.isChecked())
        {
        result= 1;
        }

      result+=1;


      if (r18.isChecked())
        {
        result= 1;
        }


        else if (r19.isChecked())
        {
        result= 0;
        }

       else if (r20.isChecked())
        {
        result= 1;
        }

     result+=1;

     if(r21.isChecked())
     {
         result=0;
     }

     else if (r22.isChecked())
      {
        result= 1;
      }

    result+=1;

     if (r23.isChecked())
     {
        result= 0;
     }


     else if (r24.isChecked())
        {
        result= 0;
        }

    else if (r25.isChecked())
        {
        result= 1;
        }

     result+=1;


       if(r26.isChecked())
           {
         result=0;
          }

     else if (r27.isChecked())
     {
        result= 1;
     }
       result+=1;



           resultAll=result1+result2+result3+result4+result5+
             result6+result7+result8+result9+result10;



    outputresult.setText(+result );   


    }       






        public void goResult(View v) 
        {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(v.getContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent2,0);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep all answers in an array or vector and try to change it according to selected radiobuttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep an `ArrayList<String>` in your `Application` class.

While user navigates from any of Question Screen, add the answer to that ArrayList.

And on last screen, use that ArrayList to display all the results selected by user.

Example:

```
public class TestApplication extends Application {

    //Object declaration
    ArrayList<String> myArrayList;

    public TestApplication () {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
    }

    //setter getter for object
}
```

Now in your Activities:

```
//after setContentView
TestApplication testAppObj = (TestApplication) getApplication();

//retrieve as:
myArrayList = testAppObj.getMyArrayList ();
myArrayList.add("User's selected answer");

//save before navigating
testAppObj.setMyArrayList(myArrayList);
```

In your last activity:

```
//retrieve as:
myArrayList = testAppObj.getMyArrayList ();
```

You must register your Application class in your manifest file just like you register your activities:

```
<application
        android:name="com.pkg.test.TestApplication " />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Can I contact you through an email?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using separate Activity for every question, you can use a singleton class to hold the answers. E.g.:

```
    public class AnswerHolder{
        public static AnswerHolder instance=null;
        public static AnswerHolder getInstance(){
            if(instance==null){
                instance=new AnswerHolder();
            }
            return instance;
        }
        private int answers[];
        private AnswerHolder(){
            answers=new int[10];
        }
        public void setAnswer(int index, int answer){
            answers[index]=answer;
        }
        public int[] getAnswers(){
            return answers;
        }
    }
```

Then in the result page, you can get the answer from it.

Comment: is that possible to develop quiz app without using database?

Comment: please explain in details how i going to use your code

Comment: If you do not use database, you mean hardcoding the answers in the app. It is possible.

Comment: You can store the answers in strings.xml using string-array tag

Comment: If your quiz app is showing questions one by one, and you want to carry the user's answer through Activities, you can use the AnswerHolder.setAnswer() method to store the user's answer to a specific question one by one

Comment: In the result page, you can use AnswerHolder.getAnswers() to retrieve all submitted answers and determine the score